# Load/initialize Java servlet on server startup

Tags: java, servlets, initialization, startup, websphere-liberty

I have a Java servlet I would like to load & initialize on **server** startup.  I assumed I could just add `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` to my `<servlet>` registration in my `web.xml` file but I find it still takes a "first request" to cause my app server (WebSphere Liberty) to actually load and initialize the servlet.

I have also tried registering a `ServletContextListener` in the same `web.xml` to no avail (it, too, is not called until that "first request").

Everything I read talks mostly about controlling the *order* of servlet loading/initialization, or, with regard to `ServletContextListener`, how you can be notified when your webapp is loaded.  I find nothing that specifically talks about *when the **server** starts up*.

For your reference, here is my `web.xml`:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>startup</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.your.mother.StartupServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>startup</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/startup</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.your.mother.MyListener</listener-class>
</listener>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_servlet_load.html

```
<webContainer deferServletLoad="false"/>
```

Comment: Awesome!  Exactly what I was looking for.